# How to JUnit Test a Wicket Page

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, wicket

I've got the following Wicket Page which serves a PDF:

```
public class TestPage extends WebPage {    
  public TestPage(PageParameters pageParameters) {
        String param1 = pageParameters.get("test").toString();
        String param2 = pageParameters.get("test1").toString();
        [..]
        try {       
            byte[] generatedPDF= generatePDF(param1, param2, pdfGenerationOptions);
                RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) requestCycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest();
                requestCycle.replaceAllRequestHandlers(new ResourceRequestHandler(new PDFResource("test.pdf", request.getHeader(USER_AGENT), true), null));
        } catch (PdfGenerationException | IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("error", e);
            new PageProvider(ErrorPage.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void renderPage() {
        // left blank
    }
}
```

How would it be possible to test if the page returns a byte array (pdf) or the ErrorPage.class since I can only call the constructor in this case?

thanks in advance

Comment: Some advice. You are doing too many things in your constructor where is should be kept simple.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to use a mounted resource instead of a page that serves binary data (pdf).

About the testing:

To test a page do:

```
WicketTester tester = new WicketTester();
PageParameters parameters = new PageParameters();
parameters.set("test", "TEST");
parameters.set("test1", "TEST1");
tester.startPage(TestPage.class, parameters);
// tester.startResourceReference(TestResRef.class, parameters);
```

1) in the successful case use `tester.getResponse().getBinaryContent()` to get the `byte[]` and assert its content.

2) in the non-successful case just use `tester.assertRenderedPage(ErrorPage.class)`